# Error when stating presto

Tags: cassandra, presto

I tried to install Facebook presto on a single node following this [link](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html).
The node has this configuration :

## node.properties

```
node.environment=prestotestcluster
node.id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
node.data-dir=/home/ogama/presto/data
```

## jvm.config

```
-server
-Xmx1G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
```

## log.properties

```
com.facebook.presto=INFO
```

## config.properties

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

I've also configured a cassandra catalog in `<presto_install>/etc/catalog/cassandra.properties` :

```
connector.name=cassandra
cassandra.contact-points=localhost
```

When i tried to start presto with `launcher run`, i get the this error :

and i get the following error :

```
4) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
  while locating io.airlift.jmx.JmxModule$JmxAnnouncementProvider
  while locating io.airlift.discovery.client.ServiceAnnouncement annotated with @com.google.inject.multibindings.Element(setName=,uniqueId=267, type=MULTIBINDER, keyType=)
  at io.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryModule.configure(DiscoveryModule.java:68) (via modules: io.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryModule -> com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder)
  while locating java.util.Set<io.airlift.discovery.client.ServiceAnnouncement>
    for parameter 1 at io.airlift.discovery.client.Announcer.<init>(Announcer.java:70)
  at io.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryModule.configure(DiscoveryModule.java:63)
  while locating io.airlift.discovery.client.Announcer
    for parameter 1 at io.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryModule.createMergingServiceSelectorFactory(DiscoveryModule.java:120)
  at io.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryModule.createMergingServiceSelectorFactory(DiscoveryModule.java:120)
  at io.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryModule.createMergingServiceSelectorFactory(DiscoveryModule.java:120)
  while locating io.airlift.discovery.client.MergingServiceSelectorFactory
  at io.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryModule.configure(DiscoveryModule.java:72)
  while locating io.airlift.discovery.client.ServiceSelectorFactory
    for parameter 0 at io.airlift.discovery.client.ServiceSelectorProvider.setServiceSelectorFactory(ServiceSelectorProvider.java:49)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.CoordinatorModule.configure(CoordinatorModule.java:135) (via modules: com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule -> com.facebook.presto.server.CoordinatorModule)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.airlift.jmx.JmxModule$JmxAnnouncementProvider.get(JmxModule.java:67)
    at io.airlift.jmx.JmxModule$JmxAnnouncementProvider.get(JmxModule.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
```

Any ideas about this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.
I've solved may issue by changing may java version.

Comment: Which version you have upgraded to?

Answer (score 0):

Do you, by any chance run the prestodb in chrooted environment? That was the issue for me, I haven't dig too deep, just tried running it in full-featured Debian Jessie VM in Virtualbox and it ran just fine.